# Store UIImageViews in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, nsmutabledictionary

I have simple question. This is my header file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstFaceController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableDictionary *face1Layers;

@end
```

This .m, here i init my Dictionary and put where UIImageView :

```
#import "FirstFaceController.h"

@implementation FirstFaceController

@synthesize face1Layers;



-(void) dealloc {
    [face1Layers release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.face1Layers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [self.face1Layers setObject:
            [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"]] 
                 forKey:@"pic"];

    [self.view addSubview:[self.face1Layers objectForKey:@"pic"]];
    if ( [[face1Layers objectForKey:@"pic"] superview] == nil ) {
         //....
    }
}
```

Then i call `[[face1Layers objectForKey:@"pic"]` superview] i have "EXC_BAD_ACCESS". 
Why?

Comment: try this... self.face1Layers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

Comment: how did you create `self.view`?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are trying to check with the if-statement. If you call `[self.view addSubview:[self.face1Layers objectForKey:@"pic"]];` then `[self.face1Layers objectForKey:@"pic"]` will always have a superview unless `self.view` does not exist.

Comment: Did you try `[self.face1Layers objectForKey:@"pic"]` instead of `[face1Layers objectForKey:@"pic"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
NSMutableDictionary* tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
self.face1Layers = tempDict;
UIImageView* picView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"]];
[self.face1Layers setObject:picView forKey:@"pic"];
[picView release];
[tempDict release];
```

Do not create and insert yours `NSMutableDictionary` and `UIImageView` throught a single line of code because you have leaks.

In the first case, if you do the following you have a retain count of two. face1Layers has a retain policy.

```
self.face1Layers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

You can avoid this splitting the code as I explained before or send an `autorelease` message to the initialized object.

In the second case, when you add an object in `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` (and theirs subclasses), these classes retain added objects.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This also creates a leak, as the property retains the mutableDictionary: `self.face1Layers = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];`

Comment: and this code is leaking `face1Layers`, as - because of the retaining property — it has an retain count of 2. the line `self.face1Layers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];` is ok.

Comment: Why should OP change a valid line of code to 3 lines of code?

Comment: @vikingosegundo Yes. You're perfeclty right. But for me, having three lines of code instead of one, it implies to have greater control on memory management. In objective-c coding I usually follow this way. Thank you. P.S. Sorry if I misspelled your username. Cheers.

Comment: and I trust in apple's engineers memory management capabilities.

Comment: I also trust in apple's memory management mechanism. But I don't trust in mine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think there are a couple of things wrong here:

1. You never allocate the dictionary as in NSMutableDictionary alloc init
2. The UIImageView is allocated but never released. I would allocate before setting it as object, and then add it, and then release it

Comment: OP is retaining the autoreleased dictionary immediately through the property. the line `self.face1Layers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];` is ok.

Comment: oh really? You don't need the alloc init anymore then using self.? I didn't know

Comment: [NSMutableDictionary dictionary] is a convenience method for [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease]. It returns an autoreleased object, if your property has the retain attribute the property will retain the object.